# count en XQuery

Tags: xml, sql

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente código XML:

```
<cliente>
<dni>55555555E</dni>
<nombre>Yen Yegua Yerbal</nombre>
<telefono>688888888</telefono>
<deuda>50</deuda>
<password>123</password>
<perros>
    <perro>
        <chip>555A</chip>
        <nombre>Linux</nombre>
        <raza>Beagle</raza>
    </perro>
    <perro>
        <chip>555B</chip>
        <nombre>Windows</nombre>
        <raza>Yorkshire terrier</raza>
    </perro>
</perros>
</cliente>
```

¿Cómo podría obtener el número de perros?. Este cliente está dentro de un XML del que "cuelgan" otros clientes, partiendo de la siguiente consulta:

```
            {
            for $x in doc("clinican.xml")/clinican/clientes/cliente

            return
                <tr>
                    <td>{data($x/dni)}</td>
                    <td>{data($x/nombre)}</td>
                    <td>{data($x/telefono)}</td>
                    <td>{data($x/deuda)}</td>
                    <td>{count($x/perros)}</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

¿Cómo podría obtener ese "count"?, porque ahora mismo me devuelve 1 independientemente al número de perros que tenga el cliente.

Necesito listar todos los clientes, pero en la última posición de la tabla necesito un número, el número total de perros.

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado la solución, el error se debía a que debía de "pedir" el número de items de tipo "perro", en concreto fallaba la línea:

```
<td>{count($x/perros)}</td>
```

Y se soluciona asi:

```
<td>{count($x/perros/perro)}</td>
```

¡Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

count(for $x in doc("clinican.xml")/perros/perro
return $x)

Comment: No funcionaría, ten en cuenta que hay muchos otros perros asociados a otros clientes, al no hacer distinción en tu código, retornaría la suma de todos los perros, no solo de los asociados a ese cliente.

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy vaga, considera añadir una descripción de lo que pretendes con este código para que sea una buena respuesta.

Comment: Tienes razón, en la próxima pregunta intentaré ser más exhaustivo. Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de contestar. Un saludo.